# How to send a Request Body in GET method using the Java 11 HttpClient library?

Tags: java

I have to request data from an API but the API needs a JSON in the request body and it has to be sent using the GET method. My project uses the Java 11 HttpClient library so I want solutions that only include using this library. How do I send the body in GET method?

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
                  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                  .GET(BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonObject.toString()))
                  .build();
HttpClient client = AppHttpClient.getInstance();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: What do you mean by a body of GET ???

Comment: Even if technically it is possible to send body in GET request (RFC 2616) better to avoid this practice.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the code?  What result did you expect?  What result did you observe instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code issue**

Builder class doesn't have a predefined GET method with the ability to pass request body. In this case just use more generic approach:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
                  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                  .method("GET", BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonObject.toString()))
                  .build();
HttpClient client = AppHttpClient.getInstance();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

**General**

Usually, passing **body in the GET** request is **not recommended**, so I would recommend reconsidering your API design. Instead of a body, you can use URL query parameters or think about using the POST method if the request body is quite big and can't be mapped to the query parameters.